# Maven parent - sharing bom dependencies with child artefacts

Tags: java, maven, parent, parent-pom, maven-bom

I have several Maven artefacts, who are all children of a parent which is used to centralise versions of dependencies in use.

For example, `apple` and `pear` are both children of `maven-parent`.
`maven-parent` defines version `3.12.0` of `commons-lang3` and both children declare a dependency of `commons-lang3`, but do not need to specify the version and are consistent.

This works well, but I'd like to use the Google Cloud libraries in both `apple` and `pear`.
The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/bom) says this needs to be done using a `bom` `dependencyManagement` entry.

I've got this working on a per-project basis, but I can't get this centralise - both `apple` and `pear` would like different parts of Google Cloud but both should be using the same version of the libraries to do so.

This is especially important as `pear` depends on `apple` and could end up overriding it's dependency versions if not careful.

What I'd like to do is move the declaration of the version of Google's `libraries-bom` version of `24.0.0` into `maven-parent`.

`maven-parent`'s `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" child.project.url.inherit.append.path="false">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>apple</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

`apple`'s `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>apple</artifactId>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>24.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-translate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`pear`'s `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>pear</artifactId>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>24.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>apple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Just move the BOM to the parent POM. We do this all the time.

Comment: @J Fabian Meier - do you have an example please?

Comment: Just take the dependencyManagement entry and move it to the parent level.

Comment: @J-Fabian-Meier Thanks, that was the first thing I tried but didn't work for some reason. But now does. Frustrating.